# Deriving a general formula for potential of a vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Suppose $F = (P,Q)$ is a vector field that is irrotational so that $\text{rot} (F) = Q_x - P_y = 0$.

Then, show that $F$ is conservative with a potential function of $$f(x,y) = x \int_0^1{P(tx, ty)  dt} + y\int_0^1{Q(tx,ty)dt}.$$

We can suppose that $F$ is defined on a convex domain including the origin.

What I've tried:

I want to differentiate $f$ with respect to $x$ and hopefully recover $P$. So, product rule yields $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \int_0^1P(tx, ty)dt  + x\int_0^1{tP_x(tx,ty)dt}+y\int_0^1{tQ_x(tx,ty)dt}.$$

If $F$ has rot $0$, then $Q_x = P_y \implies$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =\int_0^1P(tx, ty)dt  + x\int_0^1{tP_x(tx,ty)dt}+y\int_0^1{tP_y(tx,ty)dt}.$$

I'm not sure where to proceed from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please do not just post homework questions without any effort. Show us what you've tried and ask a specific question where you get stuck.

Comment: I tried differentiating wrt x and y, hoping to get P and Q back, and made the substitution of $Q_x$ =  $P_y$, but got stuck after that.

Comment: You need to post the details of your work. We aren't mind-readers here. I'm sure there will be an easy suggestion once you do that.

Comment: Edited, I hope this helps. I'm just not sure what else I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good. Now group the last two terms as
$$\int_0^1 t\big(xP_x(tx,ty)+yP_y(tx,ty)\big)dt = \int_0^1 t\frac d{dt}P(tx,ty)\,dt.$$
Can you finish now?